# Converting datas in string to integer

Tags: python, string, machine-learning

I need some advice, i have some data like example (new york, los angeles, miami, new york, dallas, etc). And i want to convert this list to number like (1, 2, 3, 1, 4, etc) in python. What keywords is it or how to do it?

I have searching for hours and just found how to convert the dataype. I want that data of some cities to become some number for data mining.

Comment: Have a look at encoding. (Label Encoding and One Hot Encoding)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [LabelEncoder](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) from scikit-learn.

Example (from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)):

```
>>> le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
>>> le.fit(["paris", "paris", "tokyo", "amsterdam"])
LabelEncoder()
>>> list(le.classes_)
['amsterdam', 'paris', 'tokyo']
>>> le.transform(["tokyo", "tokyo", "paris"])
array([2, 2, 1]...)
>>> list(le.inverse_transform([2, 2, 1]))
['tokyo', 'tokyo', 'paris']
```

Answer (score 0):

With a sample dataframe as the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'cities': ['new york', 'los angeles', 'miami', 'new york', 'dallas'], 'values': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]})
print(df)

        cities  values
0     new york     100
1  los angeles     200
2        miami     300
3     new york     400
4       dallas     500
```

You can do the following to get the codes:

```
df['code'] = pd.factorize(df['cities'])[0]
print(df)

        cities  values  code
0     new york     100     0
1  los angeles     200     1
2        miami     300     2
3     new york     400     0
4       dallas     500     3
```

If you want to set specific codes for each city you can do the following instead.

```
mappings = {'new york': 14, 'los angeles': 21, 'miami': 35, 'dallas': 0}
# Set your desired codes in te mappings dictionary
df['code'] = df['cities'].map(mappings)

print(df)

        cities  values  code
0     new york     100    14
1  los angeles     200    21
2        miami     300    35
3     new york     400    14
4       dallas     500     0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary assigning a number to a city:

```py
CityDict={
    "new york" : 1,
    "los angoles" : 2,
    "miami" : 3,
    "dallas" : 4,
}
```

Then replace the list of data by the index:

```py
cities=["new york", "los angeles", "miami", "new york", "dallas"]
cityindexes=[CityDict[x] for x in cities]
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pretty different approach to solving this question.

Create a dictionary for the items where the key represents the city name and the value represents the number(index)

```
cities = {'new york': 1, 'Tokyo': 2, 'Miami':3, 'Dallas': 4}
data = ['new york', 'Tokyo', 'Miami', 'new york', 'Dallas']
```

then create a list from the data available using a list comprehension to create the list from the ids

```
cities_id = [cities[city] for city in data]
print(cities_id) // [1, 2, 3, 1, 4]
```